# MaaS on Ubuntu Server 17.10

Tags: maas

According to https://maas.io/, you need to install it on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

I'm wondering if it's possible install it on 17.10 ?

Has this every be done before ?
What are the drawbacks ? 
Is there any support planned for this version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maas` package is simply another package in the Ubuntu repositories.

Yes, you can install it in 17.10. Yes, it is supported.

17.10 will be supported for only about four more months. Sometime during the window of April-June 2018, you must release-upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 to maintain support.

Comment: Interesting. I supposed they ask people to use 16.04 since it's supported for a longer timeline than 17.10 ?

Comment: Fair enough. Even taught these are gonna be student project servers, that will be wiped every week or so.

Comment: @Tolsadus you have clearly thought this out. Sometimes folks here don't. Kudos for thinking it through!